# An application to show words on display

Tags: vocabulary, software

Me and my coworkers are very inclined to learn foreign languages and decided to rotate a constantly updated list of words on displays that we have around the office.

To work such application is a pretty straightforward thing to do - such web application is something one can prototype literally in a half hour. But still it would be nice to find some existing application which is dedicated to exactly these purposes: to show some words in order to memorize them.

It would be nice if someone point me at such application.

Comment: @TommiBrander edited to make it clear.

Comment: What do you mean by showing the words? Like a powerpoint?

Comment: @AnthonyPham well,  short big font text. yes, pretty much presentation mode-like.

Comment: Just words? Chosen on what basis? How would the meaning be shown (translation, images, ...)? In what context would these words be looked at?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe - phrase - just some phrase and it's translation.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking. Do you want a web application with a list of common words that is updated over time?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a *presentation*, you might want to consider... well, a presentation software like [Google Slides](https://www.google.com/slides/about/), [Microsoft Powerpoint](https://office.live.com/start/PowerPoint.aspx#), or a website like [Prezi](https://prezi.com/start/).

Though they do not *specifically* target displaying items for memorization, you can make various presentations to do so. Just pick a learning strategy and make some simple slides.

- If you do a definition-word strategy, using [StudyStack](https://www.studystack.com/), creating a set of flashcards, and choosing Auto Play would work. Example [set](https://www.studystack.com/flashcard-2563830).
- If you are a visual learner, then you could try creating a slideshow with the image and/or the definition and the word.
- If you learn with sound then try [Quizlet](https://quizlet.com/latest). Simply select a set of flashcards (that you created), press Play, go to options and turn on Audio and the cards will be autoplayed with sounds. Example [set](https://quizlet.com/211461606/science-review-flash-cards/).

Of course, if you just plainly display the words, a slideshow program would work best.

Comment: Well, the tricky part  here is that presentation is not something one can bind to a dynamically updated dataset - each time you add new words, you need to update the doc itself. Also, it needs to be in the cloud since multiple displays. Also, random mode. But yes, presentation software is the bare minimum and this is a valid answer.

Comment: @shabunc The first is quite hard to solve but the latter is usually solved with websites that applies flashcards like StudyStack and Quizlet with the Shuffle options